# How can I call a statement or method after the loop complete on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            items() {
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If the loop complete, I want to call a statement or method

So the statement is executed when the loop completes

How can I do it?

Update :

From Kira San answer, I try like this :

```
  <template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(item, key) in items" v-for-callback="{key: key, array: items, callback: callback}">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            ...
            computed: {
                items() {
                    const n = ...
                    return n
                }
            },
            directives: {
              forCallback(el, binding) {
                  let element = binding.value
                  if (element.key == element.array.length - 1)
                  if (typeof element.callback === 'function') {
                    element.callback()
                  }
                }
            },
            methods: {
                callback() {
                    console.log('v-for loop finished')          
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The console log not display

My items is object

If do console.log(n) in items, the result like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  computed: {
    items() {
      return {item1: 'value1', item2: 'value2'}
    }
  },

  methods: {
    callback() {
      console.log('v-for loop finished')
    }
  },

  directives: {
    forCallback(el, binding) {
      let element = binding.value
      var key = element.key
      var len = 0

      if (Array.isArray(element.array)) {
        len = element.array.length
      }

      else if (typeof element.array === 'object') {
        var keys = Object.keys(element.array)
        key = keys.indexOf(key)
        len = keys.length
      }

      if (key == len - 1) {
        if (typeof element.callback === 'function') {
          element.callback()
        }
      }
    }
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(item, key) in items" v-for-callback="{key: key, array: items, callback: callback}">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems it is the same as my code. But why my code does not work

Comment: Well, I can't tell but there must be something else not working in your case. Try posting the code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: See my question. I had update it. My items is object. Maybe that's why it's not working

Comment: @TrendingNews Ok, I updated my answer. Now it works with arrays and objects as well.

Comment: I want to ask. Eg I have 3 loops. How to call the statement when the loops is complete

Comment: You can add a counter to your vue component that increments each time a loop is finished. then watch the counter value. if it becomes = 3 then all your loops are complete.

Comment: If you need an example, just ask a new question and I will give you one.

Comment: Ok. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213139/how-can-i-call-a-method-after-the-loopsmore-than-1-loop-complete-on-vue-js

Comment: Very useful example: I'm surprised this has not had more upvotes. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with a `directive`.

**Example usage:**

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="(item, key) in items" v-for-callback="{key: key, array: items, callback: callback}">
  <!--content-->
</div>
```

Create a new directive `for-callback` which will keep track of the elements that was rendered with `v-for`. It will basically check if the current `key` is the end of the `array`. If so, it will execute a `callback` function that you provide.

```
Vue.directive('for-callback', function(el, binding) {
  let element = binding.value
  if (element.key == element.array.length - 1)
    if (typeof element.callback === 'function') {
      element.callback()
    }
})
```

Or if you don't want to define it globally. Add this to your component options instead:

```
directives: {
  forCallback(el, binding) {
      let element = binding.value
      if (element.key == element.array.length - 1)
      if (typeof element.callback === 'function') {
        element.callback()
      }
    }
}
```

`v-for-callback` expects an options object.

```
{
  key: key, // this will contain the item key that was generated with `v-for`
  array: items, // the actual `v-for` array
  callback: callback // your callback function (in this example, it's defined in the component methods
}
```

Then in your component options:

```
methods: {
    callback() {
        console.log('v-for loop finished')          
    }
}
```

Comment: This code : `Vue.directive('for-callback', function(el, binding) {
  let element = binding.value
  if (element.key == element.array.length - 1)
  if (typeof element.callback === 'function') {
    element.callback()
  }
})`. Where the code is placed? I am still confused. Is in the export default {...}?

Comment: Just put it in your main javascript file before creating your vue instance.

Comment: @TrendingNews See my edited answer. You can define the directive directly in your component as well.

Comment: If the code executed, it not display the console.log

Answer (score 0):

You can do with an if inside the loop, like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(item, index in items)">
            <div v-if="index === items.length -1">
                Display what ever you want here 
            <\div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Or if you want to do something in js then call a function when the same  condition is true, like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(item, index in items)">
            <div v-if="index === items.length -1 && lastIteration()">
                Display what ever you want here 
            <\div>
        </div>

methods: {
  lastIteration() {
     alert("last");
}
}
```

I didn't test it but the ideea is good and it should work. Hope to answer your question :)